# Create a report from word or pdf documents

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, report

My goal is to create report in WPF using dev express. I want to add word or pdf documents into report.

For word documents, I am opening word document into RichEditControl, saving it into memory stream as rtf document and using XRRichText control, I am adding rtf document into report.

```
public void CreateReport()
{
    RichEditControl richEdit = new RichEditControl();
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    XRRichText rtfDoc = new XRRichText();

    richEdit.LoadDocument(@"word document path", DocumentFormat.OpenXml);
    richEdit.SaveDocument(stream, DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.DocumentFormat.Rtf);

    rtfDoc.LoadFile(stream, XRRichTextStreamType.RtfText);
    rtfDoc.WidthF = 550F;

    this.Detail.Controls.Add(rtfDoc);
    this.RequestParameters = false;
    this.CreateDocument();
}
```

Is this a recommended way to add word document as rtf? 
and also, Instead of word document, how can I add pdf document into report?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [XtraRichEdit - Document Server (available now in v2011, volume 1)](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/rachelreese/archive/2011/05/13/sneak-peek-winforms-richedit-document-server-coming-soon-in-v2011-volume-1.aspx) blog post, which may be helpful.